# How to disambiguate function templates that differ only by return type?

Tags: c++, templates

I have noticed that there is an asymmetry between the signature used to distinguish unique template functions, and the signature used to distinguish unique functions (including those instantiated from template functions).

In particular, template functions that differ only by return type are considered to be unique, whereas functions that differ only by return type are considered to be redundant.

Therefore, I have a corresponding question about how to disambiguate between function templates that differ only by return type, at the point of instantiation:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
long foo(T)
{
    std::cout << "long" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template<typename T>
char foo(T)
{
    std::cout << "char" << std::endl;
    return '\0';
}

int main()
{
    double d = 0.0;
    long n = foo(d); // <- Ambiguous: How to specify the template function to use?
}
```

In the above code, the instantiation of the template function `foo` is ambiguous precisely because of the asymmetry I've just mentioned.  The presence of the two template function definitions is legal, but the instantiation is illegal, even though the return type is specified in the same line of code.

I am asking this question purely for theoretical learning purposes.  Perhaps this code construct, in real life, would be a sign of poor design.  Perhaps it would never arise in real life.  Also, I can envision different ways of overcoming this issue by changing the template definitions (or by making other changes).

However, I would nonetheless like to know if, keeping the template definitions unchanged, it is possible to disambiguate between these two template functions at the point of instantiation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using templates you can actually disambiguate the two different overloads. It ain't pretty but works:

```
long n = static_cast<long(*)(double)>(&foo)(d);
```

Comment: +1, Never thought about this. Ugly but correct. BTW, `static_cast<long(&)(double)>(foo)(d)` reduces 1 character :)

Comment: Perfect.  Now my faith in function templates is restored.  I was beginning to wonder why function template signatures include return type - if they can't ever be disambiguated.  But, as your excellent answer reveals, they can.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to have two function templates having the same names, same list of parameters, but different return types, you have no choice but differentiate the two by making the return type a template parameter:

```
template <typename R, typename T>
R foo(T);
```

IIRC there is partial function template specialization in C++11, although I could not find anything about it in the standard. If there is, this should work:

```
//partial function template specializations: C++11 only!
template <typename T>
long foo<long, T>(T)
{
    std::cout << "long" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template<typename T>
char foo<char, T>(T)
{
    std::cout << "char" << std::endl;
    return '\0';
}
```

Or else, in C++03:

```
template <typename R, typename T>
struct FooImpl;

template <typename T>
struct FooImpl<long, T>
{
  static long doIt(T) 
  {
    std::cout << "long" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct FooImpl<char, T>
{
  static char doIt(T) 
  {
    std::cout << "char" << std::endl;
    return '\0';
  }
};

template <typename R, typename T>
R foo(T t)
{
  return FooImpl<R, T>::doIt(t);
}
```

In both cases, your main would look like this:

```
int main()
{
    double d = 0.0;
    long n = foo<long>(d); // specify the return type only
    auto c = foo<char>(n);
}
```