# Why does casting a function to a function type that is identical except for return type fail?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the return type part of the function signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature)

Following up on a related but tangential question ( [How to disambiguate function templates that differ only by return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684264/how-to-disambiguate-function-templates-that-differ-only-by-return-type) ), I would like to ask a question related to the fact that the *return type* of a function is not considered to be part of the signature of a function.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo()
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    long n = static_cast<long(&)()>(foo)(); // Error: incorrect return type
    int p = static_cast<int(&)()>(foo)(); // Compiles just fine 
}
```

The line of code noted above results in a compilation error, because the *return* type of the function type to which `foo` is being cast does not match the *return* type of the function `foo`.

But I thought the return type of a function does not play a role in the signature of the function!

According to a certain line of thinking, since the function signature `long(&)()` matches the signature of `foo`, the cast of `foo` to a function of this type should succeed.

However, the cast does not succeed.  Where does the reasoning go wrong?  If the cast cannot fail due to the function signature, then why does the cast fail?

Comment: @AndreasBrinck I already know that the return type is not part of the function signature.  That's not what I'm asking.

Comment: You're assuming that a cast to a function reference type only requires the same signature. That assumption is incorrect. It requires the same parameters and return type (in other words, the same function type).

Comment: @Dan If you read the answer I referred to you'll see that it explicitly answers your question!

Comment: @AndreasBrinck I thought "duplicated question" means that the question itself is a duplicate.  Am I incorrect?  Is a question a duplicate if the answer appears within the answer to a *different* question?

Comment: @Dan It’s a duplicate if the answers to the other question would equally apply here. In the linked question that’s the case (although it would have been possible that the other question got answered in a way that didn’t answer your question).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct that the return type doesn't form part the *signature* of the function.

However, it does form part of the *type* of the function, and you're not allowed to convert pointers to incompatible function types.

Comment: Beautiful, concise answer.  I wish I could accept multiple answers.

Comment: Note to those reading: Please see David's answer for additional useful related information.

Answer (score 4):

The return type **is** part of the type, although not used for *overload resolution*. It is important not to confuse the terms. Basically, the type includes arguments and return value, but during overload resolution, the return type is not considered. The *type* of the function or function pointer is a contract between the caller and the callee, and they must fully agree on the terms.

From a practical point of view, consider what would happen if what you suggest was allowed. Imagine a calling convention in which the caller reserves space and passes a pointer to that space to the function, the function will then construct in that location the returned object (this is actually a *very common* calling convention). Consider now that you were allowed to perform the cast you proposed and the following use case

```
static_assert(sizeof(T1)<sizeof(T2));
T2 f();
T1 (*p)() = &f;

p();                                  // call
```

Now when the compiler is processing `p()` it reserves space somewhere, and given the type of the function it needs to reserve `sizeof(T1)`. It then calls the function, which ends up calling `f` which writes `sizeof(T2)` bytes into the location causing an overflow.

Even if the sizes matched, the code would be problematic. Consider `T1==int` and `T2==float` in a platform where `sizeof(int)==sizeof(float)`. While the code above would not cause a buffer overrun, the bitpattern stored in the location of the return type would be that of a `float`, not that of an `int`.

Comment: This answer and David's go together.  I wish I could accept both.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of a function is not part of the signature, but the signature isn't what the compiler needs to know in order to correctly call the function referred to by a function pointer or reference.

As well as the parameters, the compiler needs to know the return type, so that it can make space for the return value on the stack, or read the return value from the correct register(s), or whatever the calling convention demands in a given implementation.

That is why the return type is part of the type of the function -- so that the type tells the compiler what it needs to know at compile time in order to emit code to call the function.

> the function signature `long(&)()` matches the signature of foo

`long(&)()` isn't a function signature, it's a *type*. `foo(void)` is a (representation of a) function signature. It includes the name and parameters. But you never need to specify a function signature in C++ code (well, perhaps as a string passed to `dlsym` or similar). The definitive representation of a function signature is the *mangled name* of the function in a given implementation. The mangling scheme isn't standard, it's up to the implementation (although if different implementations want to call into each other's libraries then they must use the same scheme, so the OS might specify one).

Comment: Thank you.  This answer, as well as Mike's and David's, are both excellent.

Comment: There is the issue of whether the mangled name is guaranteed to correspond to the function signature - that doesn't seem like a guarantee.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: it doesn't follow immediately, but C++11 does say that the signature is used for linking. The mangled name can include things that aren't part of the signature, though. The most obvious is something to specify what calling convention to use, on systems like Win32 that have more than one. That's outside the scope of the standard and so it isn't mentioned as part of the definition of the signature. All I meant by "definitive representation", though, is that `foo(void)` isn't a formal syntax. Mangled C++ names do specify the signature, and *possibly* other things.

Comment: It seems that both the function *type*, and the function *signature*, are used for linking.  I am curious in which case the *signature* is specifically used during the linking stage (as opposed to the type), and in which case the *type* is specifically used during the linking stage (as opposed to the signature).  This is related to another question I've just posted, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687607/is-the-only-purpose-of-a-function-signature-as-opp-to-type-to-define-dupl .

Answer (score 0):

The return type of a function **is** considered part of its signature (and of its type). However, it is allowed to assign function pointers to variables with different return types if the return types are "covariant".

Comment: "The return type of a function is considered part of its signature" -- For regular non-template functions, it isn't (look for [defns.signature] in the C++ standard if you doubt it), but whether it's part of the signature is simply not relevant.

Comment: Are you sure?  I am nearly certain that the return type of a non-template function is *not* part of its signature.  See, for example, the question linked in Andreas Brinck's comment beneath the question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature ).