# Is the *only* purpose of a *function signature* (as opp. to type) to define duplicates in a potential overload set - or are there other purposes?

Tags: c++, overloading

Related to [Why does casting a function to a function type that is identical except for return type fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685262/why-does-casting-a-function-to-a-function-type-that-is-identical-except-for-retu), I would like to understand, in a fuller way, the distinction between a function's *type* and a function's *signature*.

For example, the *type* of a function must typically be considered when dealing with function pointers, and the type of the function includes the return type of that function.

However, as noted in Mike Seymour's answer to the above-linked question, the *signature* of a function is different from the *type* of a function.  The signature is certainly used to disambiguate from among potential overloaded functions (noting that the return type of functions does not play a role in identifying unique functions).  But, I would now like to understand the relevance and importance of function signatures vs. function types.  It occurs to me that the *only* purpose of function signatures in C++ is to identify overload candidates and/or unique functions in an overload set, during overload resolution.

Am I correct?  Is overload resolution the only purpose of function signatures in C++?  Or are there any other uses/applications of function signatures, besides (or only indirectly related to) overload resolution?

**ADDENDUM** For clarity, please note that I am *specifically* seeking to understand the distinction between the purpose of a function **signature** and a function **type**.  I.e., I know that a function type is required both for the use of function pointers, and for a compiler/linker's implementation of a calling convention.  However, the calling convention is relevant only after overload resolution is complete.  I am here asking, specifically, if the only purpose of the function *signature* (as opposed to *type*) is for overload resolution.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  I do not see this question asked anywhere else, and this question has a specific answer that illuminates something important about C++.

Comment: I'm not sure, which is why I upvoted you. It's almost cruel in my opinion to downvote without an explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does casting a function to a function type that is identical except for return type fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685262/why-does-casting-a-function-to-a-function-type-that-is-identical-except-for-retu) and [How to disambiguate function templates that differ only by return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684264/how-to-disambiguate-function-templates-that-differ-only-by-return-type)

Comment: @Kyryx How is this a duplicate question?  I just asked both of the questions you've linked.  This question is in a related area, but it is not the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct?

As far as I'm concerned, there are other purposes too. Consider that C also has function signatures but doesn't have overloading.

Apart from overloading, the fundamental purpose of function signatures is conforming to the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) of a particular platform.

When a function accepts arguments and returns values, the compiler needs to know the type and the size of the arguments in order to pass them correctly to a function. In general, function arguments are pushed onto the stack (this is not a universal rule though, especially on 64-bit architecture systems). Consider the following situation. If you call a function like

```
foo(42);
```

how does the compiler know what is the size of the integer value it has to pass to the function? The number `42` can be represented using various bit width, for example as a 1, 2, 4  (or even 8)-byte integer:

```
00101010
0000000000101010
00000000000000000000000000101010
```

Now if the function doesn't have a signature which tells that, for instance, the argument is a `char` (which is 1 byte), or a `short` (which may be 2 bytes) or an `int`, which may be 4 bytes, then the compiler has no way of determining the correct size. It means that if it pushes an arbitrary number of bytes to the stack, but the function expects another size, then stack corruption occurs.

Another good example is returning structures (`struct`). Usually, primitive return values (such as integers and floating-point numbers) are returned in a register; this is generally the `EAX` register on x86. But what if one wants to write a function returning a struct? if the overall size of the struct is so large that it doesn't fit into a register, the compiler must generate code that pushes the return value onto the stack as opposed to assigning it to a register. So if a function is defined as

```
int foo()
{
    return 1337;
}
```

or as

```
struct bar {
    int a;
    char b[16];
    float x;
};

struct bar foo()
{
    struct bar ret;
    ret.a = 0;
    memcpy(&ret.b, "abcdefghijklmno", sizeof(ret.b));
    ret.x = 3.1415927;
    return ret;
}
```

different assembly (and machine code) will be generated - the first function that returns an integer will use the `EAX` register for storing the return value, but the second call will **have to** use the stack.

Comment: The *calling convention* must include the full function type, including the return type. I provided some cases in the linked question. Basically for *large* objects (don't fit registers) in most calling conventions (all I know of) the caller reserves space for the returned object and passes a hidden pointer to the function. The caller must know how much space it needs to allocate for the returned object and how to interpret the bits, so it is part of the *contract* between caller and callee. The **type** of the function (not the *signature*) is what the calling convention works with.

Comment: "The calling convention must include the full function type, including the return type" - of course. (I hope what I'm saying here does not contradict that.) And yes, this is a contract, indeed - I believe my first example about arguments is also part of this. The point about the hidden pointer is right; for example, that's how Objective-C "methods" return stuctures (the signature of the corresponding messenger function is `void objc_msgSend_stret(void *ret, id self, SEL _cmd, ...);`.

Comment: This answer seems to discuss the function's *type*, rather than the function's *signature*, correct?  Granted, that the calling convention requires knowledge of the return type of the function.  However, I am asking not about the calling convention and the function's type (which is applicable only *after* overload resolution), but rather I'm asking about overload resolution and the function's signature.  Am I misunderstanding the answer?

Comment: @H2CO3: I guess I did not understand the answer then, what are you suggesting the use of the *signature* is?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I'm sure you are not, I suspect I'm rather misunderstanding the question. In fact, I couldn't completely deduce from your question whether you are interested in this or in something else.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas are you asking this from me or OP?

Comment: Let me clarify the question to indicate that I am referring to the function's signature *as opposed to* the function's type.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Would it create even more confusion if I said that sometimes this thing is called a "type signature"? :P

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Also, Mike Seymour pointer out that "the return value is not part of the signature but it is part of the function type". Is it not what you are asking for, basically?

Comment: @H2CO3 Perhaps it can be said that a function's *type* contains, by definition, a superset of the information in the function's *signature*.  If so, then it makes sense to say "type signature", because that would refer to the subset of information within the function's type that corresponds to the function's signature.  I would also like to know if I'm correct that a function's type is a superset of a function's signature.

Comment: @H2CO3 Mike Seymour's answer, distinguishing between a function's type, and a function's signature, caused me to wonder in what circumstances the function's **type** (specifically) is necessary and relevant, and, in contrast, in what circumstances the function's **signature** is necessary and relevant.  (If they weren't relevant for different situations, there would be no distinction made between them.)  After thinking about it, I could not think of any scenario in which function *signatures* are relevant, besides overload resolution.  Hence my question.

Comment: @H2CO3 Am I correct that the answer is still undetermined?  If so - perhaps you could modify your answer to remove the "No" beneath the quote "Am I correct?"?

Comment: @H2CO3 Just curious, but I feel that the conversation within these comments has resulted in the conclusion that what you mean, in your answer, is that `the fundamental purpose of function **types** [rather than *signatures*, as you say] is conforming to the calling convention of a particular platform`.  If so, then I'd think the first sentence of your answer (after my quote) is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 2):

The standard mentions that signatures are used for name mangling and linking.

That being said, name mangling is not standarized. The return type is redundant in a function symbol (since there is only one possible return type for a function with a given name and arguments in a valid program, it is not required to differentiate two different symbols), but even then some ABIs do include the return type of a function in the mangled name, probably as a way of double checking that there is no violation of the rule above.

Comment: It could be argued that *name mangling* <--> *function signature* are simply different ways of saying the same thing.  In other words, if functions are considered unique specifically according to their signature, then name mangling only needs to consider the signature.  Another way of expressing this point: if (theoretically) the return type *were* considered to be part of the signature, then name mangling would have to include the return type.  So this is a bit of a tautology.

Comment: Sidenote: as far as I know, name mangling is only required because C++ permits overloading.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: It is not really a tautology in the sense that in current systems, as mentioned in the answer, the inverse direction is broken: you cannot overload based solely on return type, **but** name mangling can include that piece of information. Additionally, for function templates the return type is part of the signature, although again, you cannot have multiple specializations that differ solely on the return type...

Comment: @H2CO3: C++ has different constructs that require name mangling. Overloading is one of them. Member functions, namespaces, ... are some of the others.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes, now that you say... Thanks for the idea! Basically C++ needs name mangling because some of its capabilities that doesn't exist in C (and are usually related to OO or other higher-level programming paradigm).

Comment: @H2CO3 name mangling isn't required at all. For example, given a linker that understood C++, a toolchain could simply store C++ specific data rather than trying to encode information relevant to C++ into the traditional C data structure (which is nothing but the name; thus name mangling). The C++ committee has expressed hope that someone would do this, but as far as I know it hasn't been seriously attempted.

Comment: @bames53 That's interesting. How would you approach "storing C++ specific data", by the way?

Comment: @bames53 Even for a fully C++-aware toolchain, wouldn't the name need to be mangled in order to disambiguate between identically-named functions?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum No, because the linker wouldn't operate solely based on the name. Names wouldn't need to be unique.

Comment: @H2CO3 new object file formats to hold new data structures at least. Instead of identifying functions by just a name it would use a data structure designed to store the entire type, namespace, etc. Everything that's currently stored using name mangling.

Comment: @bames53 Question: Don't current compilers/linkers already store at least a limited data structure corresponding to each function type, and refer to this data structure using the mangled name?  I say this because the return type is not always stored within the mangled name.  In fact - might it be the case that for some current compilers/linkers, the information contained in the mangled name is never used, that the presence of the type information in the mangled name is a historic artifact, and that the only purpose of the mangled name is as the identifier for a lookup?  (I have no idea.)

Comment: @bames53: I can see why there are no implementations of that feature, or maybe you can consider that *all* do: the mangled name is  the serialization of those data structures into a string following an implementation defined protocol.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum As far as I know all implementations just use the mangled name. Additional info might be stored as optional debug info but it's not necessary.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Recall the answer I provided: even thought the implementation could potentially not add the return type to the mangled name, the fact is that some do. Those implementations need no extra information outside of the mangled name to extract all they need to link.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Indeed - I was just curious about whether existing compilers/linkers actually *use* the information in the mangled name, or whether modern-day compilers actually do use a lookup table and the information contained within the mangled name is just a historic artifact (I had no idea one way or the other).  Now, I know that the information contained in the mangled name is, in fact, used by modern-day compilers/linkers.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes, that's one way of looking at it. I'm not sure what real problems would be solved by designing a new scheme to replace the historically driven name mangling.