# Why are argument modifiers (i.e., 'const' or 'volatile') not considered part of a function's type or signature?

Tags: c++

Note that the following two functions have the same type and signature:

```
void foo1(int t) {} // foo1 has type 'void(*)(int)', and signature '(*)(int)'
void foo2(const int t) {} // Also type 'void(*)(int)', signature '(*)(int)'
```

(the `const` is not part of the function type or function signature).  Similarly, a modifier (`const` or `volatile`) on the return type does not influence the function type or function signature.

However, in the function definition itself (not shown), the named variable `t` does maintain the `const` qualification in `foo2`.

There are many StackOverflow questions discussing why the *return type* of the function is not considered as part of the function signature (used for overload resolution).

However, I cannot find any StackOverflow question that asks why argument modifiers (`const` or `volatile`) are not part of the function's type or signature.  Also, I have looked directly in the C++11 standards document and find it difficult to unravel.

What is the rationale behind the fact that argument modifiers (i.e., `const` and `volatile`) are not part of a function's type or signature?

**ADDENDUM** For clarity, from R.MartinhoFernandes's answer below, I should clarify that in C++ (I think) the argument modifiers `const` and `volatile` are only ignored as part of the function type/signature if they are **top-level** modifiers - see that answer below.

Comment: The return type *is* part of the function signature. It just isn't considered for resolving overloads. The two are separate ideas.

Comment: I can't give you the official C++ answer, but from a user's perspective they would make no difference.  If a user calls foo1 or foo2, the user will do so with an int.  It's in the implementation that the const modifier will have an effect.  Since a signature is basically the interface (what the user cares about), not differentiating would make sense.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't think so - see, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687607/is-the-only-purpose-of-a-function-signature-as-opp-to-type-to-define-dupl

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I think Dan is right. Definition of signature from the standard: "<function> name, parameter type list (8.3.5), and enclosing namespace (if any)" and the parameter type list contains all argument types with top level cv-qualifiers removed.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes The return type is *not* a part of the signature in non-template functions.

Comment: Let's say `foo1` and `foo2` in your question were two overloads called `foo`. Which would you expect to be called in `foo(1)` and why?

Comment: @juanchopanza oh, that's right. Interesting. I guess I have been doing too many templates to have noticed that. Not sure if that's good or bad.

Comment: @NPE If there were ambiguity, as in your example, *AND* if (theoretically) the `const` qualifier were part of the function type, then the compiler could issue an error and require you to specify the function type explicitly via `static_cast<void(&)(const int)>(foo)(1)` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684264/how-to-disambiguate-function-templates-that-differ-only-by-return-type

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What is the rationale behind the fact that argument modifiers (i.e., const and volatile) are not part of a function's type or signature?

From a caller's perspective, there is no difference between `void foo(int)` and `void foo(int const)`. Whatever you pass to it will not be modified, regardless of the modifier: the function will get a copy.

From an implementer's perspective the sole difference is that with `void foo(int x)` you can mutate `x` (i.e. your local copy) in the body, but you cannot mutate `x` with `void foo(int const x)`.

C++ acknowledges these two perspectives. The caller's perspective is acknowledged by making the two declarations `void foo(int);` and `void foo(int const);` declare the same function. The implementer's perspective is acknowledged by allowing you to declare a function as `void foo(int x);` but define it as `void foo(int const x)  { /*...*/ }` if you want to make sure you don't accidentally assign to the argument.

Note that this only applies for top-level `const`, i.e. `const` that applies to the whole type. In things like `int const&` or `int const*` the modifier only applies to a part of the type, as "pointer to (const (int))", so it is not top-level `const`. In `int *const` however, the `const` again applies to the whole type as in "const (pointer to (int))".

Comment: Does this reasoning apply for function signature `void foo(const int &)`?

Comment: @Dan no, only for the so called "top level `const`". In `const int&` (aka `int const&`) the `const` only applies to the referred part (`int`), not to the whole type.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't understand the distinction between "top level" and non-top level.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Note that while a `const` reference, like `int& const`, is a syntactic impossibility, it can occur as an artifact of template type deduction. Consider `const T` where `T` is `int&`.